# Is there a Flutter widget for an action button with a built-in dropdown list

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter app, the user can specifies some input text, and they can select what language they want to translate it to.

Right now I use an `ElevatedButton.icon` and a `DropdownButton` for that interaction:

[image]

While this works, I wonder if there is a single widget that shows this one integrated UI element, so a single element where they can click the button itself to trigger the `onPressed` event, and press a chevron on the right to change the language and trigger the `onChanged` event.

Is there a Flutter widget that combines the two elements above into one?

Comment: If it is possible please attach an image of the button you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a default one, but you could add the desired child into the Elevated button. So i.e. something like this:

[image]

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    print("Do stuff");
  },
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.computer),
          Text('Translate to'),
        ],
      ),
      PopupMenuButton(
        itemBuilder: (c) => [
          PopupMenuItem(
            value: '1',
            child: Text('English'),
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Or you could use a DropdownButton inside the ElevatedButton instead of the PopupMenuButton to get the selected language presented.

[image]

Of course, add styling and colors to make it look better afterwards.

With some styling and simple state management, I'd personally go for a ElevatedButton together with a PopupMenuButton (perhaps change the icon to a chevron) and after the text "Translate to" append the selected language, to get the look below. I could see this working fine as long as your list of languages isn't too long. If your app plans on translating "all" languages then perhaps DropdownButton or some alternative widget with filter capabilities is better. Or have a separate view where favorite languages can be selected then go for the version below and present only those..

[image]

Rough code for this last button:

```
class ElevatedMenuButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const ElevatedMenuButton({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<ElevatedMenuButton> createState() => _ElevatedMenuButtonState();
}

class _ElevatedMenuButtonState extends State<ElevatedMenuButton> {
  String? selected;
  final languages = ['English', 'Swedish'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        print("Button pressed with selected value: ${selected ?? languages.first}");
      },
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              const Icon(Icons.computer),
              Text('Translate to ${selected ?? languages.first}'),
            ],
          ),
          PopupMenuButton(
            onSelected: (v) => setState(() {
              selected = v;
            }),
            itemBuilder: (c) => languages
                .map((l) => PopupMenuItem(
                      value: l,
                      child: Text(l),
                    ))
                .toList(),
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```